# MySQL: Add a condition on a subquery from a joint table

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

### Get all the rooms which this "user" is part of and list each room details including its

- **id** (`roomId`)
- **name** (`roomName`)
- **total active users of this room** (`activeUsers`)
- **total users included in the room** (`totalUsers`)

Provided with the table structure below:

```
Table:users
+---------+-------------------------+
| id(int) |  active(bool/tiny int)  |
+---------+-------------------------+

Table:rooms
+---------+----------------------+
| id(int) |  name(varchar(255))  |
+---------+----------------------+

Table:room_members
+-------------+---------------+
| userId(int) |  roomId(int)  |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I'm kind of lost with my SQL so far:

```
SELECT
    rooms.id,
    rooms.name,
    (SELECT SUM(users.active) FROM users WHERE room_members.roomId = rooms.id) activeUsers,
    (SELECT COUNT(users.id) FROM users WHERE room_members.roomId = rooms.id) totalUsers
FROM room_members
INNER JOIN rooms
ON room_members.roomId = rooms.id
INNER JOIN users
ON room_members.userId = users.id
WHERE room_members.userId = 1
```

Basing from this data:

[image: sample users data]

I can conclude that I've got the wrong results.

[image: capture of mysql query]

I guess I need some help from you guys.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: seem that the two subquery are select value for users but users yable in not joined in subquery ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dynamic table with group by ( and a join between user and room_members)

```
SELECT
  rooms.id,
  rooms.name,
  t1.activeUsers,
  t1.totalUsers
FROM room_members 
INNER JOIN rooms  ON room_members.roomId = rooms.id
INNER JOIN users  ON room_members.userId = users.id
INNER JOIN  (  
                SELECT roomId, SUM(users.active)  as activeUsers, COUNT(users.id) as totalUsers
                FROM users 
                INNER JOIN room_members on users.id = room_members.userId
                group by roomId
            ) t1 on t1.roomID = rooms.id
WHERE room_members.userId = 1
```

Comment: Hi! I have edited a little your answer and I think you got it right. As of now, I'm satisfied with the query. Thank you :)

Comment: @mr5  . well if my answer is correct and/or useful please marki is as accepted and/or rate as useful .... thanks

Comment: Done. Thanks for the heads-up!